# Shared Preference fetching previous URL in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save my URL using Shared Preference and the URL keeps changing for every second. Now my problem is when I try to fetch the URL with the Shared Preference variable, it is fetching previously saved URL and not the current URL and also when I run my app for first time it is showing blank but second time it is showing the URL that should have come first time.

This is my code.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("temp", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
editor.putString("name", url);
editor.commit();
```

And to retrive the URL I wrote it in this way.

```
SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("temp", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
String name=preferences.getString("name","not loaded");
```

What should I do ?

Comment: May be there is problem with the code you are doing. Shared Preference Store and Retrieve process is perfect. But as you say is storing url every second so may be when you retrieve and see at that time url get changed. Try to put Log at both the process store and retrieve. This will give you exact idea.

Comment: Is your url is changing at runtime when the app is running?@Reaching-Out?

Comment: I checked it. Lets say I'm opening the app at 1:00, 5:00, 7:00. Now If I first open it at 1:00 after installation it shows blank , then when I open it at 5:00, it is passing the URL which should have come at 1:00 and If I open it at 7:00 it is opening the 5:00 URL . I know this cause I'm passing the time along with URL .

Comment: @ CrazyAndroid. No the URL does not change at runtime. It just fetches the URL at that particular time and keeps it that way and when I close it and open it again it changes.

Comment: what url should come at 1 pm. I think you first retrieving and then you store.

Comment: yes I'm retrieving and storing it and use the variable which has stored that URL to load the webview

Comment: @Reaching-Out: it means  application is getting url from `SharedPreferences` before updating latest in it. plz explain more about senior when u are saving url in `tSharedPreferences` and getting from it

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K. I am clearing the contents available in that Shared Preference and storing the URL every time as you can see in my code . Then where am I going wrong ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K. I couldn't follow U. Can u please elaborate it. Even If it is getting URL from Shared Preference before updating it, then how should I change. As you can see I'm loading the URL and then I'm reading it.

Comment: @Reaching-Out: please explain more when u are saving and retrieving  url in Preference. or show more code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K . I retrieve the URL from RSS feed where the URL keeps updating for every second with the time appended along with the URL. Now I need to save this URL in shared preference so that I can use this for some other reason and use the variable which I have used to save the URL to load the webview. This is the flow. Is there anything else u needed ?

Comment: @Reaching-Out: `use this for some other reason and use the variable which I have used to save the URL to load the webview` you are loading url in Webview before getting latest url from `rss feed` ?

Comment: I'm passing the latest URL to shared preference every time but for some reason it is fetching only the previous URL. That's what I still don't get it .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110956/discussion-between--k-and-reaching-out).

Answer (score 0):

`MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` was there to refresh data from disk every time. Because multiple processes could be modifying preferences data and data loaded in memory for one process wouldn't have changes from other process. It has been deprecated for not working reliably.

As far as your particular problem, I'd recommend something like:

```
public class PrefStore {
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "app_prefs";
    private final SharedPreferences mPreferences;

    public static final String KEY_URL = "key_url";

    public PrefStore(Context context) {
        mPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void saveUrl(String url){
        mPreferences.edit().putString(KEY_URL,url).apply();
        Log.i("PREF_TEST",String.format("Write URL:%s at:%s by thread:%s",url, new Date(), Thread.currentThread().getId()));
    }

    public String getUrl(){
        String url = mPreferences.getString(KEY_URL,null);
        Log.i("PREF_TEST",String.format("READ URL:%s at:%s by thread:%s",url, new Date(), Thread.currentThread().getId()));
        return url;
    }
}
```

Log will help you inspect whether its a timing/thread problem.

Comment: So which mode should I follow for my case then ? Is it OK to go with PRIVATE

Comment: @Reaching-Out If no other app is going to ever access preferences data but your own app, then  `MODE_PRIVATE` should be used. So, yes.

Comment: No ,no other app is using it. Then can you please tell me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: I'm getting the URL inside AsyncTask task and am loading the webview outside AsyncTask task . If that's the case then how would I call these methods

Comment: @Reaching-Out To get the latest url, you'll have to call `getUrl()` **after** `saveUrl()`. Its a timing issue.